# Focus on input to display a console log message from if/if else conditional?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, events, input

I'm stuck as to why when I "focus" on the input, it doesn't display my console log message unlike if it's empty or not empty, it'll display the message. Am I using the event wrong?

(Only a portion of my code, if needed more details, please let me know)

The HTML

```
<input id='input' placeholder="President Name" type="text">
```

The JS

```
function message() {
   var presidentInput = document.getElementById('input').value;
            if (presidentInput === "") {
                console.log('Please enter something in the input');
            } else if (presidentInput !== "" || document.getElementById('input').onfocus){
                console.log('Great job');   
            }
        }
message();
```

Comment: how message() function get called, is it through some events. Pls add more details

Comment: Hi, you need to add an event listener or can add onfocus attribute. Example - <input id='input' placeholder="President Name" type="text" onfocus="message()">

Comment: You need add an event handler to your input element, either through adding onxxx="yourhandler();" attribute to input or add it programmatically by using addEventListerner method. In your sample, your message function just run once when you call it.

Comment: your code seems fine, the only issue may be with browser console, may be you turn off the console, or try checking in different browser

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = document.getElementById('input');

jQuery.input.focus(function(){
  if(input.value === ""){
    console.log('Please enter something in the input');
  else{
    console.log('Great job');
  }
});
```

Maybe this code isn't correct.

But, the key point is using event Listener on input TAG.

```
input.addEventListener("focus", function(){
      if(input.value === ""){
        console.log('Please enter something in the input');
      else{
        console.log('Great job');
      }
});
```

Comment: Including jQuery here may just confuse the poster more

Answer (score 0):

just use onblur event.
check this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp)

you are not binding any event. you are just calling the message function after declaring it. That is why, it only logs 'Please enter something in the input'.